# Data Cleaning with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe column consisting of text data and I need to filter it according to the following conditions:

- The character "M", if it's present in the string, it can only be at the n-2 position
- The n-1 position of the string always has to be a "D".

ex:

> KFLL
>
> KSDS
>
> KMDK
>
> MDDL

In this case, for example, I would have to remove the first string, since the character at the n-1 position is not a "D", and the last one, since the character "M" appears out of the n-2 position.

How can I apply this to a whole dataframe column?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? I don't see any attempts ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's with a list comprehension:

```
l = ['KFLL', 'KSDS', 'KMDK', 'MDDL']

[x for x in l if ((('M' not in x) or (x[-3] == 'M')) and (x[-2] == 'D'))]
```

Output:

```
['KSDS', 'KMDK']
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want. Could probably be written down shorter with list comprehensions, but at least this is readable. It assumes that the strings are all longer than 3 characters, otherwise you get an IndexError. In that case you need to add a try/except

```
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(["KFLL", "KSDS", "KMDK", "MDDL"]), columns=["code"])
print("original")
print(df)
mask = list()
for code in df["code"]:
    flag = False
    if code[-2] == "D":
        counter = Counter(list(code))
        if counter["M"] == 0 or (counter["M"] == 1 and code[-3] == "M"):
            flag = True
    mask.append(flag)
df["mask"] = mask
df2 = df[df["mask"]].copy()
df2.drop("mask", axis=1, inplace=True)
print("new")
print(df2)
```

Output looks like this

```
original
   code
0  KFLL
1  KSDS
2  KMDK
3  MDDL
new
   code
1  KSDS
2  KMDK
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

I ended up implementing it like this:

```
l = {"Sequence": [ 'KFLL', 'KSDS', 'KMDK', 'MDDL', "MMMD"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data= l)

print(df)

df = df[df.Sequence.str[-2] == 'D']

df = df[~df.Sequence.apply(lambda x: ("M" in x and x[-3]!='M') or x.count("M") >1 )]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Sequence
0     KFLL
1     KSDS
2     KMDK
3     MDDL
4     MMMD
  Sequence
1     KSDS
2     KMDK
```